Окно печати открывается через раз в яндекс-браузере
Для печати из браузера на принтер создаю отдельное окно с содержимым и его печатаю. В chrome это работает исправно, а в яндекс-браузере работает крайне нестабильно - окно создается, но диалог печати открывается нормально только первый раз. Если диалог печати закрыть - окно с содержимым закрывается, но при повторной печати окно с содержимом создается и отображается, а вот диалог печати уже не открывается. Иногда открывается после нескольких попыток.
Версия яндекс-браузера: "24.7.6.1026 corp", но и в других версиях поведение такое же.
Если после формирования окна с содержимым руками в консоли вызвать "print();" - диалоговое окно печати открывается.
var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=50,top=50,width=1024,height=800,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,status=0');
WinPrint.document.write("<link rel = 'stylesheet' href = '/css/site.css'>");
WinPrint.document.write(html);
WinPrint.document.close();

WinPrint.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
 WinPrint.focus();
 WinPrint.print();
 WinPrint.close();
});

